# Totality of the $\leq$ relation on the class of all cardinal numbers

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I was just wondering how to prove that the $\leq$ relation on the class of all cardinal numbers is total, that is:

$$\forall \text{ sets }A, B.\qquad |A|\leq|B|\quad\text{or}\quad |B|\leq|A|.$$

By the way: $|A|\leq|B|$ is just a symbolic notation for saying

*'there is an injection from A to B'*.

Comment: One needs choice in order to prove this. And then the usual approach is to show that for any set $A$ there is a unique initial ordinal $\kappa$ such that $A \cong \kappa$. Since ordinals are linearly ordered by inclusion, this implies your claim.

Comment: Actually, I wanted to prove the totality of the ≤ relation on the class of all cardinal numbers just in order to prove that for every set A that is not finite, there is an injection $\mathbb N_+\to A$. Is it necessary to prove the totality of the ≤ relation on the class of all cardinal numbers in order to prove that for every set A that is not finite, there is an injection $\mathbb N_+\to A$ or is there an easier proof of this theorem?

Comment: It is consistent to have an infinite set that doesn't have a countable subset. So, in fact, you need at least some choice in order to prove your claim.

Answer (score 1):

It's actually equivalent to the axiom of choice. You may reduce to prove that if there is no surjection $X\to Y$ then there is an injection $X\to Y$ (since under the axiom of choice the existence of a surjection $X\to Y$ is equivalent to the existence of an injection $Y\to X$ EDIT: except if $Y=\emptyset$, but it's a trivial case).

Consider the set $E$ of all $(A,f)$ where $A\subset X$ and $f:A\to Y$ is injective, ordered as usual $(A,f)\leqslant (B,g)$ iff $A\subset B$ and $g_{|A}=f$.

Clearly this order is inductive (just take the union in a chain to get a supremum), so there is a maximal element $(A,f)$.

Suppose $A\neq X$, and take $a\in X\setminus A$. By hypothesis, $f$ can't be surjective so there is some $x_0\in X$ not in the range of $f$. Then you can extend $f$ to $A\cup \{a\}$ by $f(a)=x_0$ which is still injective. Contraduction.

So $A=X$ and $f$ is your injective function.

Comment: You are asserting that "under the axiom of choice the existence of a surjection X→Y is equivalent to the existence of an injection Y→X". But I think there is an injection $\emptyset\to\mathbb N$ but no function (and therefore no surjection) $\mathbb N\to \emptyset$.

Comment: Ah yes the proof fails for the empty set. Doesn't change much.

Comment: Otherwise : if $f:X\to Y$ is injective, take $x_0\in X$, and consider $g:Y\to X$ such that $g(y)=x$ if $y=f(x)$, and $g(y)=x_0$ if $y$ is not in the image of $f$.